# create a function between some points in R

Tags: r, function, continuous-integration, continuous

I have two vectors for example `x` and `y`like this:

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
y <- c(0.01,0.1,0.2,0.4,0.8,0.9,0.4,0.3,0.1,0.02)
```

I want to create a continuous function `y=f(x)` in a way that it looks exactly like `plot(x,y , type='l')`, i.e., the `curve(f, min(x), max(x))` look exactly like the `plot(x,y , type='l')` and I can calculate an integral like `integrate(f, min(x), max(x))` or other contnuous calculations with it.

Comment: How should the function behave? Do you just want straight lines connecting all those discrete points? Maybe you just want `f <- approxfun(x,y)`

Comment: I don't know. How does the 'plot(x,y, type='l')' connects the points?

Comment: Well, if you want to be able to interpret it in any meaningful way, you should probably have some idea of what's actually going on. Did you try `f <- approxfun(x,y)`? That does a basic linear interpretation which is much like how `type="l"` just draws a straight line to connect the points.

Comment: @MrFlick Actually, I have tried approxfun and it does not produce the same smoothness like the plot. The problem is that the size of x and y is around 5000 and they look so smooth in the plot (I am estimating a distribution). I want to use the points in a continuous function but I loose around 0.1% of the preciseness. Also I have tried smooth.spline which is not much different and even worse.

Comment: Type “l” doesn’t do any smoothing so it’s not clear what you might be referring to. Do you have duplicate x values? Maybe update your example so it more closely matched your real data and clearly demonstrates the problem you are experiencing.